# Help with string gauges for my vintage bass

Tags: strings, bass-guitar

I need help with my vintage 1956 Danelectro bass, its in a baritone style body and i believe its either a short or a medium scale neck. I'm just terrified of what gauge strings to give it, cause i dont want to bend the neck at all. i want to use .35-.90 but they are only extra long scale or long scale, im just not sure what to buy for it. i want super lighter strings for it. Im not sure what to do.

Comment: I'm no expert on this but I did some google searching.  You want to determine whether or not short scale strings are what you actually need, which seems to be the case based on my search.  I've seen people using .45 to .105 as well as .40 to .95.  Hopefully this link will be helpful: http://www.bassstringsonline.com/30--31-inch-Short-Scale_c_587.html

Comment: Good start point is what's on it now. Another is to establish exactly what the scale is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your own research. The bass already has strings - which can be miced up to determine gauge. Measuring from bridge to nut will give scale length. You say you don't want to bend the neck - fair enough, but if the super light strings you want for it are too light, the neck tension will *decrease* and possibly allow the neck to straighten too much! So adjustments will need to be made, was that the case.

Changing to strings that are 10-15% lighter is probably a good start point, but be prepared to change again, as you won't know if the feel (and re-adjustment) are right *for you* till you try. I say for you, as someone on this site maybe has the exact same guitar, set up in their favourite way, but that may - or may not - be one that suits you.

You already have a datum point, if it's strung already. It has to be a good start.